# Kafka Streams Transformer context.timestamp() not returning correct timestamp

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

A little background on my use case: I have to buffer a specific record (identified by a unique type) for few seconds as I need some information from another event which subsequently follows it. This second event almost every time comes within 5 seconds.  To do this I implemented buffering by using statestores where I buffer the first record for 5 seconds. I put the record into the statestore as (key, Pair<Value,T1>) where T1 is the timestamp when I process this record. If I don't get the subsequent record with 5 seconds then I want to just forward this waiting record. Once I put this record into the statestore. I run a scheduled punctuate in which I forward the records that have expired this 5 second time out.

For this I am using the wall clock timestamp extractor . I am doing all of this in a custom Transformer via the processor api. I try to get the timestamp (T1 in my example) by calling the context.timestamp(). However this context.timestamp() within the transform method is not returning the current system timestamp.
This is one such log from the transform method

DEBUG  [19:51:33.815] - record with key=** value={**} and timestamp=1621392502699.
This timestamp in the log is from the context.timestamp() and its value is Wednesday, May 19, 2021 2:48:22.699 AM which is different than the the current system which as seen in the log message is 19:51:33.815

I am also capturing the log when the punctuate is being called

This is the timestamp from the punctuate method
Punctuating @ timestamp 1621453893556.
This matches the current system time which was Wednesday, May 19, 2021 7:51:33.556 PM

I am little confused as to why the context.timestamp() when called from the transform method is not returning the current system time even though the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html) says this method will return the timestamp extracted from ConsumerRecord by TimestampExtractor

Because the timestamp not returned is correct what is happening that the records are not getting buffered for the entire 5 seconds and are getting emitted as an when the punctuate is running

Any help is appreciated

Version used is Kafka-Streams-2.3.1